# StyleSpan is not applied on SpannableString in TextView

Tags: android, styles, uitextview, spannablestring, spannable

I want to make specific substring's font BOLD.

Here is my code:

```
 String fullName = "some name";
 String searchFreeText = "some";
 SpannableString wordToSpan = new SpannableString(fullName);

Typeface helvticaBoldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD);
int startPosition = fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFreeText.toLowerCase());
StyleSpan bold = new StyleSpan(helvticaBoldTypeface.getStyle());
                    wordToSpan.setSpan(bold, startPosition, startPosition + searchFreeText.length(), 0);
 firstLineTextView.setText(wordToSpan, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The text remains not bold.
If I change the code to:

```
firstLineTextView.setTypeface(helvticaBoldTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

and remove

```
 StyleSpan bold = new StyleSpan(helvticaBoldTypeface.getStyle());
                    wordToSpan.setSpan(bold, startPosition, startPosition + searchFreeText.length(), 0);
```

then all the text is bold, and that's ok, but not what i want.
I need to make bold only specific text.
I expect to see this: **some** name.

What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed one thing:
>    **You are using FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD (Which is already bold so nothing special gonna happen to your text cuz it is already bold just change it to some regular font)**

[You can find some fonts here](https://fonts.google.com/)

> For making specific text bold and colored you can try the following code

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textToBeSpannedWithBold);

StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(styleSpan,
        positionOfSearchedText,
        positionOfSearchedText + searchTextToBeBold.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

//Use this if you wanna make specific text bold
SpannableString uncolouredSpan = new SpannableString(spannableStringBuilder);
textViewToBeBoldSpanned.setText(uncolouredSpan);

//Use this if you wanna make specific text bold plus coloured
SpannableString coloredSpan = giveMeColoredSpan(
        new SpannableString(spannableStringBuilder),
        ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.your_specific_colour));

textViewToBeBoldSpannedAndColoured.setText(coloredSpan);


public static SpannableString giveMeColoredSpan(SpannableString spannableString, int color) {
    spannableString.setSpan(
            new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
    return spannableString;
}
```

> > If Still somehow you are stuck with your problem for that i have created a repo on Github https://github.com/harsh159357/customtextview

Activity Code From My Repo

**CustomTextViewActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class CustomTextViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_COLORED = "MakeThisSpecificPartColored";
    public static final String MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD = "MakeThisSpecificPartBold";
    public static final String MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD_AND_COLORED = "MakeThisSpecificPartBoldAndColored";
    CustomTextView customTextView1,
            customTextView2,
            customTextView3;
    Button changeToRoboto,
            changeToCalculus,
            makeSpecificTextColored,
            makeSpecificTextBold,
            makeSpecificTextBoldAndColored;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_view);
        customTextView1 = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView1);
        customTextView2 = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView2);
        customTextView3 = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView3);
        changeToRoboto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_to_roboto);
        changeToCalculus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_to_calculus);
        makeSpecificTextBold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make_specific_text_bold);
        makeSpecificTextColored = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make_text_colored);
        makeSpecificTextBoldAndColored = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make_text_bold_and_colored);
        changeToRoboto.setOnClickListener(this);
        changeToCalculus.setOnClickListener(this);
        makeSpecificTextColored.setOnClickListener(this);
        makeSpecificTextBold.setOnClickListener(this);
        makeSpecificTextBoldAndColored.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.change_to_roboto:
                customTextView1.setFont(getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular));
                customTextView2.setFont(getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular));
                customTextView3.setFont(getString(R.string.font_roboto_regular));
                break;
            case R.id.change_to_calculus:
                customTextView1.setFont(getString(R.string.font_calculus_sans));
                customTextView2.setFont(getString(R.string.font_calculus_sans));
                customTextView3.setFont(getString(R.string.font_calculus_sans));
                break;
            case R.id.make_text_colored:
                makeTextColoured();
                break;
            case R.id.make_specific_text_bold:
                makeSpecificTextBold();
                break;
            case R.id.make_text_bold_and_colored:
                makeTextBoldAndColored();
                break;
        }
    }
    public static SpannableString giveMeColoredSpan(SpannableString spannableString, int color) {
        spannableString.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
        return spannableString;
    }
    private void makeTextColoured() {
        String textToBeSpanned = customTextView1.getText().toString();
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textToBeSpanned);
        int positionOfSearchedText = textToBeSpanned.indexOf(MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_COLORED);
        SpannableString coloredSpan = giveMeColoredSpan(
                new SpannableString(textToBeSpanned),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
        customTextView1.setText(coloredSpan);
    }
    private void makeSpecificTextBold() {
        String textToBeSpanned = customTextView2.getText().toString();
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textToBeSpanned);
        int positionOfSearchedText = textToBeSpanned.indexOf(MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD);
        StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(styleSpan,
                positionOfSearchedText,
                positionOfSearchedText + MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        customTextView2.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
    }
    private void makeTextBoldAndColored() {
        String textToBeSpanned = customTextView3.getText().toString();
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textToBeSpanned);
        int positionOfSearchedText = textToBeSpanned.indexOf(MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD_AND_COLORED);
        StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(styleSpan,
                positionOfSearchedText,
                positionOfSearchedText + MAKE_THIS_SPECIFIC_PART_BOLD_AND_COLORED.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        SpannableString coloredBoldSpan = giveMeColoredSpan(
                new SpannableString(spannableStringBuilder),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
        customTextView3.setText(coloredBoldSpan);
    }
}
```

**actvity_text_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextViewActivity">

        <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/customTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/roboto_regular"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:font="@string/font_roboto_regular" />

        <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/customTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/themed_text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:theme="@style/roboto_theme" />

        <com.harsh.customtextview.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/customTextView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/calculus_sans"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:font="@string/font_calculus_sans" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/change_to_roboto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Change to Roboto" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/change_to_calculus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Change to Calculus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/make_text_colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Make text coloured" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/make_specific_text_bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Make specific text bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/make_text_bold_and_colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Make text bold and colored" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks. But it didn't work. the text remains regular

Comment: I tried the following peace of code and the result is regular not bold font for the whole string in my TextView. Am I missing something?

Comment: String textToBeSpannedWithBold = fullName;
                    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textToBeSpannedWithBold);
                    StyleSpan styleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
                    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(styleSpan,
                            startPosition,
                            startPosition + searchFreeText.length(),
                            Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                    firstLineTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);

Comment: @Natalie have you changed your font which is in your assets folder to regular one cuz you are already using bold font

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this issue.
2 parts that solved it: 
setting the textview to empty string before applying style changes (`firstLineTextView.setText("");`) and using `firstLineTextView.append(wordToSpan);` instead of `firstLineTextView.setText(wordToSpan)`

Here is the code:

```
String fullName = "some name";
String searchFreeText = "some";
int startPosition = fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchFreeText.toLowerCase());
SpannableString wordToSpan = new SpannableString(fullName);
firstLineTextView.setText("");
                    wordToSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startPosition, startPosition + searchFreeText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    firstLineTextView.append(wordToSpan);
```